# Custom QToolTip.showText closes immediately

Tags: python, qt, pyside6, qtooltip

I'd like to display a tooltip when somebody selects an item from QComboBox.

My code is as follows:

```
   def on_tooltip():
      QToolTip.showText(
         self._w.combo.mapToGlobal( QtCore.QPoint( 0, 0 ) ),
         'my tooltip text',
         w = self.w.combo,
         msecShowTime=3000)


   self.w.combo.activated.connect(on_tooltip)
```

`msecShowTime` is totally ignored - as soon as the tooltip is displayed, it is closed immediately.
It doesn't matter if a pass the `w` argument.

I am using PySide6 (6.4.0.1) on Windows platform.

Thanks!

I was also trying to replace `activated` signal with overriding the `mouseMoveEvent` and enabling `setMouseTracking` (my widget is created using Qt Designer, so I cannot override my QComboBox object). But I am not receiving any events this way.

Comment: It's probably caused by the fact that the popup is being hidden, which indirectly hides tooltips. Try to call `QToolTip.showText` using a delayed QTimer.singleShot.

Comment: @musicamante,  Interesting idea, I tried it using `self.w.combo.activated.connect(lambda: QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(200, on_tooltip))`, but with exactly the same result: The tooltip opens after a delay, but closes immediately.

Comment: That shouldn't happen (200ms is a sufficient time to allow all pending events to be handled, but anyway try to increase it much more). Can you please provide a basic [mre] and also include OS/Qt info? (I don't remember if PySide and Qt version match, they don't in PyQt). Note that if you use widget promotion in Designer, you can use your own subclasses written in Python.

Comment: On my linux system, a 1 msec delay is sufficient to show the tooltip correctly. This would seem to suggest a platform-specific issue, but it's hard to be sure without seeing a proper [mre].

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that I am on Windows

Comment: @MeirTseitlin We still need a MRE. You may not be doing anything wrong or strange, but we need to be sure that we can rule out anything else before doing further research.